# Polymer | How to load Multiple sources on iron-component-page?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, backbone.js, polymer, web-component

Can we load multiple sources on iron-component-page for generating the demo DOCS. 
For Example:

```
<iron-component-page sources='["page1.html", "page2.html","page3.html"]'></iron-component-page>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file `all-imports.html` and then use it in `src` attribute of index.html file

all-imports.html

```
<link rel="import" href="page1.html">
<link rel="import" href="page2.html">
<link rel="import" href="page3.html">
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>paper-input</title>

  <script src="<>/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="<>/iron-component-page/iron-component-page.html">

</head>
<body>

  <iron-component-page src="all-imports.html"></iron-component-page>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing is while I have multiple docs now - the demos page won't appear for my behavior elements. Is there something I could be missing here?

Comment: @DavidDouglas , you specify where your demos are located inside a `<!-- html comment -->`. So it would look something like `<!-- @demo demo/index.html -->`. You can do this inside each of the imported component files. `<iron-component-page>` will pick up the `@` symbol and do it's magic.

Comment: specifically, the `@demo` html comment. There's a few more `@` comments to be aware of that do different magic as well. Have a look in the "Write Element Docs" section on the Polymer site. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/documentation#write-element-docs ...Another great resource is this documentation style guide: https://polymerelements.github.io/style-guide/

Answer (score 2):

Take inspiration from the "components/paper-input" package, which includes "paper-input" element, but "paper-input-container", "paper-input-behavior"... as well.

You'll have to replace your desired `sources='["page1.html", "page2.html","page3.html"]'` with the well-documented `src` attribute referring to a brand-new file `all-imports.html` in this way

**yourpage.html**

```
    ...
    <link rel="import" href="../iron-component-page/iron-component-page.html">
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
      <iron-component-page src="all-imports.html"></iron-component-page>
    ...
```

therefore referring your `["page1.html", "page2.html","page3.html"]` source array, through a single-line-link file

**all-imports.html**

```
    <link rel="import" href="page1.html">
    <link rel="import" href="page2.html">
    <link rel="import" href="page3.html">
```

Similarly to what Srik yet wrote.

NB: the upper left corner element drop-down, will likely appear page-children elements documentation too (in any)..